# Relationship between medication and severity of symptoms

Tags: correlation, scipy, psychology, friedman-test

I'm looking to determine whether there is a relationship between the type of medication used by an individual and their self-reported severity of symptoms.

**Independent Variable:**
Medication Type (categorical/nominal, one of four types)

**Dependent Variable:** Symptom Severity (ordinal e.g. Low, Medium, High)

**Type:** Dependent groups - multiple observations from the same person.

**Sample:**
Day - Medication Type - Severity Rating (There are ~200 samples for each subject, across the four types of medication)

I was thinking that a Friedman test might be appropriate, followed by a post-hoc Wilcoxon to determine which group (medication type) is more strongly related with lower symptom severity.

Firstly is the the right approach, and secondly, would this be the right way of structuring the samples for Python Scipy?

```
print friedmanchisquare(
scipy.array([0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 5, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 0]), # severity scores for medication type 1
scipy.array([5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3]), # severity scores for medication type 2
scipy.array([5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 2, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 2, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5])) # severity scores for medication type 3
```

How would I follow on to determine which group was best?

Thanks!